# Is Plastic Memories adapted from a manga/light novel?

Tags: plastic-memories

Is Plastic Memories adapted from a manga/light novel? If so, how many volumes/chapters have been released so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Plastic Memories (プラスティック・メモリーズ Purasutikku Memorīzu?) is a Japanese anime television series produced by Doga Kobo and directed by Yoshiyuki Fujiwara. The story was conceived by Naotaka Hayashi, who also wrote the screenplay, with original character design by Okiura. The series premiered in Japan on April 4, 2015 - [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plastic_Memories)

The anime premiered in 4/4/2015 with no manga adaptation as its an original anime only story with original anime only character designs.

There is a manga **spin-off** that's planned for 6/2015.